# How to remove SSRS navigation area?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2008

I am using the Embed Widget on a Team Foundation Server 2017 dashboard to show an SSRS report.  In particular, I would just like to either show the chart or the chart and the title.  I do not want all of the navigation information to be visible.  Is there a way for me to remove the navigation area in the rdl file or is there an option just to show the chart?

[image]

Comment: What is the version of SSRS?

Comment: Version 12.0.2569.0

Comment: OK, see my answer bellow please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool bar settings on the link to hide it.. something like this

```
http://yourreportsportal/ReportServer?/report folder/reportname&rc:Toolbar=false&rs:Command=Render
```

Please note the **rc:Toolbar=false**

Comment: I thought that would work for sure.  The toolbar still gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rc:Toolbar=false, or try rv:Toolbar=false too.
For me, rc:Toolbar=false worked.

```
http://reportsite/ReportServer?/report folder/reportname&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false
```

But there are some versions of SSRS that have a bug on that.
If none of the parameters work, I would recommend you to try to upgrade SSRS and check if there is a newer version or SP that you could apply.

You can see more reference for parameters on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference